# rewrite if/else for textbox into a single line of code

Tags: c#, if-statement

Is it possible to rewrite this into a single line of code?

```
if (txtInvoiceDate.Text != "")
{
  query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(txtInvoiceDate.Text.ToString());
}
else
{
  query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

Comment: Learn about the condition (`?:`) operator.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: I have been reading about the ?: operator. I wasn't sure how this would work in this situation. I have never used it in this case

Comment: Also learn about `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`.  What happens in your code if `txtInvoiceDate.Text` is null...

Comment: Pretty sure TextBox.Text can never be null. But it certainly could be just spaces. Or various other things that can't be parsed as a date.

Comment: So you are telling me that this code is not valid: `TextBox.Text = null;`?  `.Text` is a string property.  Since when are strings not nullable?

Comment: @maccettura The TextBox control will default the Text property to an empty string.

Comment: @LarsTech huh, I did not know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

> I have been reading about the ?: operator. I wasn't sure how this
>   would work in this situation. I have never used it in this case

So, according to your code you can change it to

```
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = txtInvoiceDate.Text != "" ? DateTime.Parse(txtInvoiceDate.Text.ToString()) : DBNull.Value;
```

but it will be better to use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`

```
query.Parameters.Add("@InvoiceDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtInvoiceDate.Text) ? DateTime.Parse(txtInvoiceDate.Text.ToString()) : DBNull.Value;
```

Read more about [?: Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: You probably should address the logic flaw in OP's code.  What happens when the textbox.Text property is null...

Comment: @maccettura yes, I follow by the logic flow in OP's code because `I wasn't sure how this would work in this situation`

Comment: You need to cast one side to `object`.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes

Long answer:

```
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtInvoiceDate.Text) ? DBNull.Value : DateTime.Parse(txtInvoiceDate.Text.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying something similar to this but having trouble finishing the line.